# Why can't Openstack find clouds.yaml (or is unable to access it)?

Tags: openstack

Openstacks configuration page says (highlights and numbering by me):

> OpenStackClient looks for a file called clouds.yaml in the following locations: I) `current directory` II) `~/.config/openstack` III) `/etc/openstack`

but when I place an openstack [`clouds.yaml`](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/configuration/index.html) at I-III), it doesn't read any data from it. [`openstack configuration show`](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/cli/command-objects/configuration.html#configuration-show) at least is not showing the additional information and calls that would require said information fail due to that information not being available to openstack.

I used the command: `openstack configuration show`

Comment: Please show us the contents of your `clouds.yaml` and the exact command line you're running and any relevant environment variables. Note that `openstack configuration show` won't show any information from your `clouds.yaml` unless you either specify `--os-cloud <name>` on the command line or set the `OS_CLOUD` environment variable (because otherwise how does it know which cloud configuration to use?).

Comment: Oh my, you are right. Can you please make this an answer even though it was a foolish question; so I can accept it? In case someone has the same issue.

Comment: I have moved it to an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openstack configuration show` won't show any information from your `clouds.yaml` unless you either specify `--os-cloud <name>` on the command line or set the `OS_CLOUD` environment variable (because otherwise how does it know which cloud configuration to use?).